Concept of hybridization
When atoms forms bond with other atoms , their orbitals take such forms that the overlap is maximum . These forms are linear combinations of orbitals . While not in any bonding , the electron can be in any form but while bonding , the form is such that they are equivalent in orientation and it's extension from the nucleus is maximum so that maximum overlap is achieved while bonding . Schrödinger equation says Such linear combination can occur only between degenerate orbitals . But in reality we see that $2s$ and $2p_{x,y,z}$ which are not degenerate also form hybridized orbitals. So how can we justify this ?

To say that only degenerate orbitals can mix is a great oversimplification.

@IvanNeretin Else it would mean that hybrid orbitals are not stationary solutions of SE

Can't answer now but you are confusing two things. In the atom the 2s and 2p are indeed degenerate eigenfunctions, and as such any linear combination is also an eigenfunction. But in the molecule they are no longer eigenstates, so in the molecule saying they are degenerate is meaningless. Instead we are using them as a basis in which to expand the MOs, which is different from the above

@IanBush , there is a small difference in energies of s and p orbitals for multyelectron atom so they are not degenerate .

When atoms forms bond with other atoms, their orbitals take such forms that the overlap is maximum. That is not true. All nuclei would fall on a single point if only maximum overlap would be the goal. Bonding involves many more parameters and is a balance between attraction and repulsion.

Your premise "Schrödinger equation says Such linear combination can occur only between degenerate orbitals" is wrong. The time-independent Schrödinger equation can be used to find out which orbitals need to be mixed to find suitable molecular orbitals. Orbitals with similar energy are more likely to mix but there is no condition of degeneracy.
